# Glade GTK accessing individual widgets

Tags: c, gtk, widget, glade, gtkbuilder

I constructed a database manipulating GUI using glade,
for my add button
hierarchy is add->confirmation dialog->(if yes)add data.
how could each widget values in the main form be accessed?
i am new to gtk and glade, i managed to get rid of most of the errors.

Comment: Can you show us your code so far? My instict is that you would grab those widgets using  gtk_builder_get_object(), and then get the data through functions specified in the Gtk reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ordinarily you would use GtkBuilder like Ethan said. As far as I know, dynamically-created widgets can't be so easily looked-up. I'd just pass a small array of pointers to the modules that need them.